# Cómo publicar los cambios de una librería (en el build.gradle) en el repo de maven

Tags: java, android, gradle

Deseo subir mis cambios al repositorio maven, ejecuto el comando gradle publish pero mis cambios no se reflejan. Especícamente no se sube el .aar
Si me pueden ayudar a identificar el problema y cómo solucionarlo

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def getVersionName = { ->
        return "1.5.6" // VERSION X.X.X : #########
    }

publishing {
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        groupId = 'com.androidx'
        artifactId = 'sielibsdroid'
        version getVersionName()
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url = "https://nexus.nexusvirtual.net/repository/.../" 
        credentials {
            username = "admin"
            password = "UuVVdCcPzixCxkMya3JshdYf"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Si ejecuto el comando *gradle publish* se publica incompleto en el repositorio de maven (sin el .aar)
[image: ejecuto el gradle publish]

[image: No se refleja el .aar]